# Should I publish this?

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics, research-undergraduate, physics

In the year 2000, someone probed the 3 dimensional quantum dots using a new condition which is important in semi conductor physics. But they basically solved the Schrodinger equation for ground state and discussed the consequences.

I have extended their work for general case , i.e, one can calculate "higher" state energy using those calculations. Also, I have pictured how the wave function looks like at higher states.

But I think that I have done just Math & some computations.

> My query is : Is this result publishable owing to the fact that I am a Junior year student and I did this work without any adviser.

Comment: It is impossible to know if this is worth publishing without reviewing the whole work and being an expert on the field. The best you can do is to find an advisor. You don't _need_ one, but without, you are likely to hit many walls.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Your question seeks specific guide which is not probable to be generalized to others in Academia. If your question is about independently publishing your work, I encourage you to visit the questions listed under the [independent-researcher tag](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher).

Answer (score 7):

As it is mentioned in the [comments](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29403/should-i-publish-this/29404#comment64085_29403), we have no access to your paper to determine whether it is a perfect paper to be published or the content is of value to be published. Also, reviewing papers are off-topic to this website.

But, if you are looking for answers regarding `[you are] a Junior year student and I did this work without any adviser`; my answer will be **YES**.

There is no obligation for anybody to send his paper for a journal to be peer-reviewed or even to publish his research. The content of the paper is more important than the education level of their writers.

However, I would recommend you to show your research paper to a faculty member. He will review your paper scientifically besides to the review he will do on the academic writing of your paper.

Also, if you want to apply for a masters or PhD program or even if you are seeking for a job; you will need recommendation letters from the faculty members (and showing your paper to a professor is one way to show that you are eligible to get one). The professor whom you will show your paper to may be so glad to write one for his smart student who has worked upon Schrödinger's equation.

Comment: Just to clarify, "you will need recommendation letters from the faculty members" if you apply to a master's or doctoral programme, or (probably) if you apply for a job. You don't need a recommendation letter to submit or publish a journal article. But it's good to be thinking about this now, and talking to faculty about the work you've done on Schrödinger's equation will help you stand out from the crowd.

Comment: +1 for "recommend you to show your research paper to a faculty member". An academic paper is a different class of beast from any kind writing you've done up to now. So even if you're a great writer, you'll almost certainly need help with your first paper. And if your results are publishable the faculty member can help you figure out the best place to submit them.

Comment: @mhwombat I edited to bring your later point to the answer.

Comment: @mhwombat The other point may be he needs support from a faculty member to respond to the letters and reviews he receives from the editor of the journal he has submitted his paper. Answering to such emails is not easy indeed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses. And by the way, I have not worked upon the Schrodinger Equation. I have *used* it along with a new condition (relatively) in semi conductor physics to bring out generalized results , the specific ones were already probed.